# creating a th tag in haml with an id that is a Ruby variable

Tags: ruby, haml

I have a table in haml and I would like the id of a table header to be able to change according to a ruby variable @title_id.
In pseudo-code, this is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
%th.@title_id
```

Answer (score 5):

That should look like this:

```
%th{:id => @title_id}
```